# Not found CSS resources from primefaces library

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm tring to use primefaces in a maven proyect runing on wildfly 26 and i getin **JSF1064** warning for diferent css components.

I coudnt find any dependency to add or other kind of solution to solve this.

```
11:51:26,418 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-43) JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, theme.css, desde la biblioteca, primefaces-vela.

11:51:26,461 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-45) JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, components.css, desde la biblioteca, primefaces.
11:51:26,441 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-41) JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, calendar/calendar.js, desde la biblioteca, primefaces.
11:51:26,462 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-45) : java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException


11:51:26,435 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-42) JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, calendar/calendar.css, desde la biblioteca, primefaces.
11:51:26,561 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-42) : java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

How can i remove this warnings?

Comment: I am using WildFly 26 and don't see these issues.  What version of PrimeFaces?  Do you have any custom componennts?